# Should I have one database or multiple?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to have multiple test runs of a device and record the reslts.

Each run will consist of

- a start timestamp
- an end timestamp
- a user supplied textual description of the test run
- a collection of measurements from various measuring devices, taken at one second intervals

Question: I have thought to create one databse for each test run (since the measurements table will have multiple rows specific to that run and I would otherwise have to add an extra column as an Index).

Am I correct to use multiple databses, or is there a better way, with a single databse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one database.  In your measurements table, add a field with a `run_id` specifying the specific run.

Example below - your field types may vary, depending on your needs.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS measurements
(
    measurement_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    run_id INT,
    start_time INT,
    stop_time INT,
    description VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (measurement_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS runs
(
    run_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    description VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (run_id)
);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, @TimDearborn. What would you suggest fro run_id? I doubt that the 64 char textual description is a good idea; not so sure about the timestamp, but do I really want to create a new value at the start of each test run? Sorry, to be such a new guy. Synatx is one thing, but concepts are another, when learning.

Comment: I would probably just make it an integer.  If you want a description, then you should make another table with the fields `run_id` and `description` or something similar.

Comment: And at the start of a new test run, I serach for the current maximum value of that integer, increment it and use it as an index into two tables, one with start time/stop time/description & the other with many rows of a dozen measurements (and an extra column for the new integer)?

Comment: Yes - the table that has dozens of measurements should have both a unique `measurement_id` field and a (non-unique) `run_id` field, both being integers.  The primary index for that table would be the `measurement_id` field.

Comment: I added a simple table definition to my answer above. You may have more fields, or may need to change the field types, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: 2 @ +1 and the answer. Thanks a 1,000,000

Comment: It'd be nice if `run_id` was of type `NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` to avoid having to generate them by hand. Same goes for the `measurements` table.

Comment: @tadman - I totally agree - modified answer to add auto-increment to indexes as you suggested.

Comment: To be thorough you'd also want an index on `run_id` for `measurements` so it's not doing dog-slow table scans all the time.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to ask, the answer is always one.

You wouldn't be asking this question if you needed more than one because you would have gone beyond *thinking* you needed multiple databases to *knowing* you do.

What you need to focus on is creating a simple schema that can handle what you want and is indexed properly so it's quick to query.

Comment: Why? Canyou explain, please? And how best to structure the single databse?

Comment: You've almost got the answer in your question. What column type would be applicable for each bit of data you're collecting? Group them all together with an identifier for the particular run, create a table for that, and you're pretty much done. This is DB101 here. Don't over-complicate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a suggestion, you need to use single database. It will help you with scalability and maintenance as far as ease of use is concerned. Using multiple DBs / schemas will pose a headache at a later stage. It is only a suggestion though.